# Most idiomatic way to read a range of bytes from a file

Tags: file, rust

I have a file, say `myfile`. Using Rust, I would like to open `myfile`, and read bytes N to M into a `Vec`, say `myvec`. What is the most idiomatic way to do so? Naively, I thought of using `bytes()`, then `skip`, `take` and `collect`, but that sounds so inefficient.

Comment: Use [`seek()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Seek.html) on `File` to skip to wherever you want to start reading and then [`read_exact()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact) to read exactly the amount you want.

Comment: Cool! But, I’d like to get the data into a Vec. Should I preallocate one full of zeros? That sounds wasteful, no?

Comment: `vec![0; 1024]` will heap-allocate a zeroed buffer of 1024 bytes in a single call to the allocator, can't get any faster than that.

Comment: Your correct in assuming `.bytes().skip(a).take(b).map(|r| r.unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>()` will be slow. It can be 200 or more times slower than the `.seek()` & `.read_exact()` approach or even much slower depending on the number of bytes skipped and taken.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *most idiomatic* (to my knowledge) and relatively efficient way:

```
let start = 10;
let count = 10;

let mut f = File::open("/etc/passwd")?;
f.seek(SeekFrom::Start(start))?;
let mut buf = vec![0; count];
f.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
```

---

You indicated in the comments that you were concerned about the overhead of zeroing the memory before reading into it. Indeed there is a nonzero cost to this, but it's usually negligible compared to the I/O operations needed to read from a file, and the advantage is that your code remains 100% sound. But for educational purposes only, I tried to come up with an approach that avoids the zeroing.

Unfortunately, even with unsafe code, we cannot safely pass an uninitialized buffer to `read_exact` because of this paragraph in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact) (emphasis mine):

> No guarantees are provided about the contents of `buf` when this function is called, implementations cannot rely on any property of the contents of buf being true. **It is recommended** that implementations only write data to `buf` instead of reading its contents.

So it's technically legal for `File::read_exact` to *read* from the provided buffer, which means we cannot legally pass uninitialized data here (using `MaybeUninit`).

Comment: About your unsafe code, this [comment](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/std/io/mod.rs.html#378) in a similar code from std source code says: "This creates a (mut) reference to a slice of _uninitialized_ integers, which is **undefined behavior**. Only the standard library gets to soundly "ignore" this...". Although there is an unstable [`read_initializer`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Initializer.html) feature that may make this reliably possible in the future.

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks! In particular, the `from_raw_parts_mut` requirement that "`data` must point to len consecutive **properly initialized** values of type `T`" is being violated here. Do you know of a way to do this without UB?

Comment: I guess you could do: `let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(count); r.take(count).read_to_end(&mut v);`, but I don't know if it will be noticeable or even worse. Anyway, IME, zeroing of buffers never has as much performance impact as people expect.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answer works, but it reads the entire block that you're after into a `Vec` in memory. If the block you're reading out is huge or you have no use for it in memory, you ideally need an `io::Read` which you can copy straight into another file or pass into another api.

If your source implements `Read + Seek` then you can seek to the start position and then use `Read::take` to only read for a specific number of bytes.

```rust
use std::{fs::File, io::{self, Read, Seek, SeekFrom}};

let start = 20;
let length = 100;

let mut input = File::open("input.bin")?;

// Seek to the start position
input.seek(SeekFrom::Start(start))?;

// Create a reader with a fixed length    
let mut chunk = input.take(length);

let mut output = File::create("output.bin")?;

// Copy the chunk into the output file
io::copy(&mut chunk, &mut output)?;
```